# What does `?:` mean?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

In an online tutorial I have seen the following snippet of code:

```
$this->data = $data ?: \Input::all();
```

Is this a standard ternary operator? What would happen when `$data` evaluates to `true`?

Does the following code do the same thing as the original I posted?

```
$this->data = $data ? null : \Input::all();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) and all these http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+body%3Aternary+is%3Aquestion

Comment: @MikeB - Wasn't a duplicate question. toro2k edited my question so now it has become a duplicate of another.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a ternary operator, shortcut of

```
 $this->data = $data? $data : \Input::all();
```

From http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator.
>
> Expression **expr1 ?: expr3** returns *expr1* if *expr1* evaluates to TRUE, and *expr3* otherwise.

Comment: Aaah... Thanks. Not seen it done like that before, but very useful to know. I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: It's less commonly used because (1) relatively new so many devs don't know it, (2) can't use it if you want your code to work with PHP 5.2, (3) can't be used for common examples like `isset($x) ? $x : ''`, as you'd just get the boolean returned by `isset()`.

Comment: I generally use it when I should return some data from database. In this case the key of the array (generally) always exists but it can be an empty string.